How to italicise a specfic part of a legend text in ggplot?
I want to italicise in the legend the Species name in "Rescued Species" and "Wild Species".
How can I achieve it? I have looked at ggtext and glue packages but I am not seeing how to apply it to my example. The example works with any "toy" dataset. I cannot share the data (so sorry).
TM_M_WILD_plot <- ggplot(data = TM_M_WILD, aes(x = Age, y = MeasurementValue)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill= "Rescued T. manatus"), size = 4.5) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 163, ymax = 386, fill = "Wild T. m. manatus"), 
              alpha= 0.6, colour = NA) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 331, ymax = 979, fill = "Wild T. m. latirostris"), 
              alpha= 0.6, colour = NA) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black')) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Populations", values = c("royalblue", "orange", "royalblue"))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0, 0), limits=c(0, 40), breaks = seq(0, 40, 5))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0, 0), limits=c(0, 1000), breaks = seq(0, 1000, 200), guide=guide_axis(minor.ticks = TRUE))+
  labs(
    x = "Age (years)",
    y = "Body Mass (Kg)",
    title = "Body Mass per Age")+
  theme_gray(base_size = 55
  )
 
TM_M_WILD_plot


Thank you in advance for your help.

You should simplify your example (are all those theme() settings relevant?), and include enough code so it runs.  We don't have TM_M_WILD.

Try with fill = "Wild *T. m. manatus*", i.e. wrap the words you want to italicize in * and use + theme(legend.text=ggtext::element_markdown(()). See e.g. How to italicize select words in a ggplot legend?

Are you looking for something like this?

Very straightfoward. It worked. Thank you for your help.

Any idea on how do I control the size of the text? Should I add size= inside of element_markdown(())?

Yup. As with element_text you can set the font size using size=.
